# Styled component not overriding background

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

In the following, all the properties of `Button` are overriding the properties of `PillButton` ***except background***. I've tried `background-color` with the same result. Only adding `!important` to `background` works.

```js
const { white, darkGrey } = theme.colors;
export const PillButton = styled.button`
  align-items: center;
  background: ${p => (p.selected ? white : darkGrey)};
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: none;
  color: ${p => (p.selected ? darkGrey : white)};
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  white-space: nowrap;

  :hover {
    background: ${white};
    color: ${darkGrey};
  }
`;

const Button = styled(PillButton)`
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 13px;
    background: ${p =>
      p.selected ? theme.colors.draftedBlue : theme.colors.midGrey};
    font-family: "Roboto Condensed", sans-serif;
  `;

Why isn't background working?
```

Comment: whats the value of `theme.colors.draftedBlue` or `theme.colors.midGrey`? does it contain !important at the end?

Comment: Maybe problem is with `theme.colors.draftedBlue` and `theme.colors.midGrey`?

Comment: No those colors are used throughout the app with no problem.